# How do you backup / re-apply custom (not downloaded) ID3 tags on MP3s?

Tags: backup, mp3, restore, tags, id3

I've seen various players, song library managers, and other apps strip tags from mp3s.  So it's not that hard to mistakenly delete or modify tags in batch.

I've seen a lot of suggestions for automatically downloading ID3 tags for MP3s, using various applications.   But they all come from each application's crowd-sourced database (or a shared one).

How can I backup my tags locally (and by backup, I mean: be able to re-apply with ease - ie: the restore function of backing up), using *my* data, and not worrying about the crowd not doing it my way?  Preferably without just duplicating all the MP3s.

I would like my info (custom entries for id3 tags) held somewhere other than embedded in the directory tree/filenames or in only the ID3 tags (pref a text file or DB that's not buried in an application, but I might take that, too).  Ie: if your tags get wiped, and your files get moved/renamed - how do you get the custom information that you entered back?  Manually cutting and replacing each field, in each tag, for each song - after getting them changed back to the default crowd-sourced tags - is ridiculous.  I'd like a local solution, as that computer is not on the internet.

A solution might be to export every id3 field into the filename; however I have to ensure that the filename delimiter between each tag used in the name is not used within every tag - and makes for horrifically long and harder to use filenames.

Prefer windows, but other solutions are welcome.

Comment: MP3Tag has some pretty powerful [features](https://community.mp3tag.de/t/converters-to-rename-files-or-to-import-tags/8016).

Comment: There appear to be three (blog?) entries at that link.  They all talk about using filenames/directories to inform tags or the reverse: using tags to make/change directories/filenames.  I thought I wrote my question more clearly? I would like my info held somewhere other than the directory tree or the ID3 tags (pref a text file or DB that's not buried in an application, but I might take that, too).  If your tags get wiped, and your files get moved - how do you get the custom information that you entered back?

Comment: I know it's not a direct answer to your question, that's why I made it a comment. My point is that you can write scripts with that app that may accomplish what you're looking for.

Comment: I think a better link to communicate that would be: 'Maybe the scripting functions in mp3tag could be used? http://help.mp3tag.de/main_scripting.html '.  I'll investigate this some more.  The features link was not enticing, nor clear that scripting might be possible.

Comment: Tag Backup.....http://jampal.sourceforge.net/tagbkup.html

Comment: @Moab Can you write that as an answer?  It's not perfect, but it certainly meets the requirements.  I will need to fo some testing, but it looks very hopeful.

Comment: Software recommendations are frowned on here at SU, that is why it is a comment and not an answer.